# Post 500 error on cmd every time I run robotframework to open mobile application

Tags: android-studio, automation, appium, robotframework

Run on robot framework, android studio emulator and appium on cmd. I used simple open application keyword to open the android application but I receive this error every time in cmd at the end of the long response in cmd

```
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 9909 ms - 4059


----------------------------------
[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.22.2
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Robot Script

*** Settings ***
Library    AppiumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Open_Application

```
  Open Application      http://localhost:4723/wd/hub/    platformName=Android    platformVersion=11     deviceName=emulator-5554    appPackage=chat21.android.demo     appActivity=chat21.android.demo.SplashActivity - Chat21       automationName=Uiautomator2
```

Answer (score 0):

Error code 500 is due to an Internal Server Error, which means something is wrong with your server, not the request. So it is not likely to be related to robotframework.